# Change of variables when integrating over matrices

Tags: integration, matrices, change-of-variable

I have the following integral
\begin{align}
    \int f \left(U(X)\right) g \left(U(X) \right) dX
\end{align}

Where,

- $X,U(X) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$;
- $f,g: \mathbb{R}^{n \times d} \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}$.
- $f$ is a PDF and $g(X)$ is a positive function for every $X$.

The connection between $X$ and $U(X)$ is given as follow:
\begin{equation}
\label{Eq: relation}
    U\left( X \right)^{T} U\left( X \right)
    =X^{T} X + B
\end{equation}

I would like to change the integral such that the integration variable will be $V=U(X)$. It should have the general form of
\begin{align}
    \int f \left(U(X)\right) g \left(U(X) \right) dX
    &=\int f \left(V\right) g \left(V \right) 
    \det (J\left(X,V \right)) dV
\end{align}
$J\left(X,V \right)$ is some sort of Jacobian matrix, but I can't figure out what should it be and how to calculate its determinant.

Any help will be appreciated.